# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' (compare dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas, database, string, dataframe

I am a beginner at Python, and I have some issues with a code I wrote.

I have 2 dataframes: one with general informations about books (`dfMediaGe`), and the other with the names of books which were shown on TV (`dfTV`).

My goal is to compare them, and to fill the column `'At least 1 TV emission'` in `dfMediaGe` with a `1` if the book appears in the `dfTV` dataframe.

My difficulty is that the dataframes do not have the same number of lines/columns.

Here is a sample of `dfMediaGe` :

```
    Titre   original_title  AUTEUR  DATE    EDITEUR THEMESIMPLE THEME   GENRE   rating  rating_average  ... current_count   done_count  list_count  recommend_count review_count    TRADUITDE   LANGUEECRITURE  NOTE    At least 1 TV emission  id
0   La souris des dents NaN Roger, Marie-Sabine|Desbons, Marie  01/01/2021  Lito    TIPJJ001 Eveil  J000100 Jeunesse - Eveil et Fiction / Histoire...   GJEU003 Jeunesse / Mini albums|GJEU013 Jeuness...   NaN NaN ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 NaN fre NaN 0   46220676.0

1   La petite mare du grand crocodile   NaN Buteau, Gaëlle|Hudrisier, Cécile    01/01/2021  Lito    TIPJJ001 Eveil  J000100 Jeunesse - Eveil et Fiction / Histoire...   GJEU003 Jeunesse / Mini albums|GJEU013 Jeuness...   NaN NaN 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 NaN fre NaN 46220678.0
```

and here is a sample of `dfTV` :

```
    Titre   AUTEUR  DATE    EDITEUR GENRE   THEMESIMPLE TRADUITDE   NOTE    THEME   LANGUEECRITURE  FORMATNUMERIQUE PUBLIC  MATIERE LEXIQUE DESCRIPTION
0   Les strates Bagieu, Pénélope    11/12/2021  Gallimard   NaN TIPBD001 Albums NaN NaN T090200 Bandes dessinées / Bandes dessinées fre NaN NaN NaN NaN 1 vol. ; illustrations en noir et blanc ; 24 x...
```

And here is the code I wrote, which is not working at all.

```
  for Titre, r in dfMediaGe.iterrows():
    for Titre, r in dfTV.iterrows():
        p = 0
        if r['Titre'].values == (dfTV['Titre']).values.any():
            p = 1
            r['Au moins 1 passage TV'].append(p)
```

I do get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your two data frames not having the same amount of columns is a problem.

You can achieve what you are looking for using this:

```
data_dfMediaGe = [
    ['Les strates Bagieu'],
    ['La petite mare du grand crocodile'],
    ['La souris des dents NaN Roger'],
    ['Movie XYZ']
]
dfMediaGe = pd.DataFrame(data=data_dfMediaGe, columns=['Titre'])
dfMediaGe['Au moins 1 passage TV'] = 0

data_dfTV = [
    ['La petite mare du grand crocodile'],
    ['Movie XYZ']
]
dfTV = pd.DataFrame(data=data_dfTV, columns=['Titre'])

for i, row in dfMediaGe.iterrows():
    if row['Titre'] in list(dfTV['Titre']):
        dfMediaGe.at[i, 'Au moins 1 passage TV'] = 1

print(dfMediaGe)


                               Titre  Au moins 1 passage TV
0                 Les strates Bagieu                      0
1  La petite mare du grand crocodile                      1
2      La souris des dents NaN Roger                      0
3                          Movie XYZ                      1
```

All you have to do is iterate through rows in `dfMediaGe` and check if the value in the `Titre`column is present in dfTV in the `Titre` column.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's totally working !!